# Calculating value of x for which f(x) is given

Tags: python, function

This may be a simple question, but I can't wrap my head around it. Say,

```
nb = 100
tb = 25
ns = 90
ts = 15
A0 = 1
S_norm = 0.4


R = tb/ts
y_meas = (ns-nb/R)/A0
sigma_meas = np.sqrt(ns+(nb+1)/R**2)/A0    
def likelihood(y):

    def func_likelihood(x):
        return np.exp(-0.5*(((x/A0)/S_norm)**2 + ((y-y_meas*A0/np.exp(x))/sigma_meas)**2))

    return (scipy.integrate.quad(func_likelihood,-10,10))[0]
```

Is there an easy way to determine value of y such that likelihood(y) is 0.025?

Comment: You mean `func_likelihood`?

Comment: @ScottHunter, no, likelihood(y).

Comment: So really your question is whether this function is a bijection?

Comment: @DPdl You need to either determine the inverse function analytically or you could try to use numerical methods.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I see-- that makese sense. So there isn't a "quick" way to do that?

Comment: @DPdl In general, no - because not all functions are invertible, and determining a function's inverse can range from very easy to very tricky.

Comment: @DPdl Maybe have a look at [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) which might help finding the inverse function. But I don't think learning to use it beats solving this particular problem with pen and paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`scipy.optimize.fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)?

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def func(y):
    return likelihood(y) - 0.025

print(fsolve(func, 0))
```

Result:

```
[-7.3920919]
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for!